# Returning Two Sum Columns from Active record in a single result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am having some trouble getting the right output from Rails Console, even though the SQL produced seems to be correct. I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Orders.rb #Orders Model

```
scope :financials, -> {select(['SUM("orders"."totalCost") as "Cost"', 'sum("orders"."taxCost") as "tax"'])}
scope :fulfillmentstatus, -> {select('"orders"."fulfillmentstatus"')}
scope :byfulfillmentstatus, -> {group('"orders"."fulfillmentstatus"')}
```

Rails 4.1

In the console

```
Order.fulfillmentstatus.financials.byfulfillmentstatus
```

Returns the following SQL

```
SELECT "orders"."fulfillmentstatus", SUM("orders"."totalCost") as "Cost", sum("orders"."taxCost") as "tax" FROM "orders"  GROUP BY "orders"."fulfillmentstatus"
```

The result hash though has

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<Order id: nil, fulfillmentstatus: "NEW">,
#<Order id: nil, fulfillmentstatus: "WILL_NOT_DELIVER">, 
#<Order id: nil, fulfillmentstatus: "SHIPPED">,
#<Order id: nil, fulfillmentstatus: "RETURNED">, 
#<Order id: nil, fulfillmentstatus: "DELIVERED">]>
```

When I run the SQL query in against the database in postgres I get as you would expect three columns

fulfillmentstatus, Cost,  Tax

NEW              , 999.99, 9999.99

Is it possible to return two or more sum, count, avg columns/values in a single Activerecord result, or have I misunderstood what active record what for?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the inspection of ActiveRecord. If you do `Order.fulfillmentstatus.financials.byfulfillmentstatus.first["Cost"]`, you should get the correct value. Try to run `to_json` to see what the query is actually returning: `Order.fulfillmentstatus.financials.byfulfillmentstatus.to_json`

Comment: @AbM: Is right, AR's `inspect` only includes columns in the table, it won't include anything extra that you set up using `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Order.pluck(:fulfillmentstatus, :Cost, :Tax)
Not sure it works with as (column not specified in model)